# What happens if I push userdata twice using the same key?

Tags: c++, lua, lua-userdata

I would like to know what happens if I push  the lightuserdata into the registry twice using the same key.

**My Code:**

```cpp
MyData *x, *y; //let's say these are valid pointers

lua_pushstring(L, "my_data");
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, static_cast<void *>(x));
lua_settable(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);

lua_pushstring(L, "my_data");
lua_pushlightuserdata(L, static_cast<void *>(y));
lua_settable(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);

lua_pushstring(L, "my_data");
lua_gettable(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
MyData *data = static_cast<MyData *>(lua_touserdata(L, -1));

//would the data be x or y?
```

Would the previously pushed pointer (`x`) be replaced with the new one (`y`)?

**ADDED:** And is there a way to check the list of keys that are currently registered?

Comment: To check whether a field exists use: `lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "my_data"); if (!lua_isnil(L, -1)) { /* field exists, do something */ } lua_pop(L, 1);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lua registry is an ordinary Lua table. Your code is equivalent to

```
registry.my_data = x
registry.my_data = y
```

So, yes, after these two lines the value of `registry.my_data` is the value of `y`.